# Timeout on element find in Selenium with Java

Tags: selenium, timeout

When you do something like

```
WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table"))
```

you can issue a command like

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

to change the timeout.  But now, what if you want to do something like the following:

```
 public String getCellText(WebElement tab) {
 {
     WebElement td = tab.findElement(By.xpath(".//td"));
     return td.getText();
 }
```

You can't do a

```
 tab.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is there a way to change the timeout?  This is expecially interesting when you have an element that is a table, and you want to find the rows underneath, if it is possible there are no rows.  If you did a tab.findElements(By.xpath("tr")) and there are no rows it can take up to a minute to return.

Is there a way to set timeout for an element as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is a **implicit wait.**
The implicit wait is set for the **life of the WebDriver object instance**.

Since **tab** is web element , you can't do :

```
tab.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You may opt for **Explicit wait** for change the timeout for specific conditions.

Code would be something like this :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

It return a web element. you can have it like this also :

```
WebElement element =   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Comment: So what would locator be?  I usually would use By.xpath(xpath)  where xpath is the xpath.  But this needs to be relative to the element.  Can I somehow specify the locator as being relative to the element?

Comment: locator is nothing but by.xpath(xpath) ; Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: I guess I have to play around with it ;-)

Comment: Can I do a new WebDriverWait(table);   ?  (where table is a WebElement)?